# Change the cell value using REST API with APIKey

Tags: rest, google-sheets-api

I want to change the cell value in sheets.

1. Share the spreadsheet. (Read and Write)
2. HTTPS GET.
   `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SPREADSHEET_ID}/values/A4?key={API_KEY}`
3. HTTPS POST.
   `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SPREADSHEET_ID}/values/A4?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key={API_KEY}`

2 is fine. But 3 got error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to POST with APIKEY authentication?

Thanks.

Comment: The API key can be used for only the publicly shared contents. So unfortunately, it cannot be used for POST method. So how about using the access token retrieved by OAuth2 and/or service account?

Comment: Oh... Thanks for your comment. My target platform not support OAuth2 and jwt now. (Cheap embedded microcontroller)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I cannot understand about the situation that OAuth2 and service account cannot be used, in the case that you can request with only GET method, for example how about using Web Apps as a workaround? The flow of this workaround is as follows. 1. Create Web Apps using Google Apps Script. The script put the values to Spreadsheet. 2. Request to Web Apps with GET method and the values for putting to Spreadsheet. In this case, the Web Apps can be used as an API. Although there is a limitation of the size of query parameter, how about this?

Comment: I got it and will try. Thanks.